# Attention based recurrent neural network for text classification

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, theano, keras, cntk

Are there any implementations of Attention-based RNN for text classification? (in theano, Karas,....)? I found some implementations of this model but they are used more often for the text generation purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the information from:

https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Implement-an-attention-mechanism

and apply to a token classification model explained here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/Tutorials/CNTK_202_Language_Understanding.ipynb